# sqlite multiple unique isn't work

Tags: sqlite, unique-constraint

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city_recent
            (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            city_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            language BOOL NOT NULL,
            type BOOL NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES city(_id),
            UNIQUE(city_id, type) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
```

But unique don't work:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works as expected (test shown below). Most likely what has happened is that the table was created beforehand without the `UNIQUE` constraint. Try removing `IF NOT EXISTS` to confirm.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> con.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city_recent
...             (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
...             city_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
...             language BOOL NOT NULL,
...             type BOOL NOT NULL,
...             FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES city(_id),
...             UNIQUE(city_id, type) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01298FA0>
>>> con.execute('insert into city_recent(city_id,language,type) values (0,0,1);')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0129F120>
>>> con.execute('insert into city_recent(city_id,language,type) values (0,0,1);')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01298FA0>
>>> con.execute('select * from city_recent').fetchall()
[(1, 0, 0, 1)] # -> note that there is only one row in the table
```